# How to acess Azure Server via organizational account or active directory

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, ip, firewall

### Goal

I want users to access our Azure server using their organizational account. Ideally a firewall that would validate them on their username rather than an ever changing IP address due to traveling.

---

### Background

We have several cloud databases hosted with our Azure server. These databases are used by our inhouse programs which help our sales, engineers and so on.

---

### Problem

Currently we have a firewall that must have specified IPs in order for users to have access. The issue with that is we could have several sales people traveling which makes their IP change and they receive the following error:

[image]

---

Users login to Windows as CONTOSO\userName respectively. Is there a way for Azure to verify our Active Directory and see that the current username is a legitimate person who should have access to our server?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with an Azure Server? a Virtual Machine?

Comment: @PeterBons In the azure portal I have an SQL server which contains SQL Databases. I have a firewall protecting that via IP addresses. I want to connect to that using organizational accounts instead of specifying IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes that you are using a Virtual Machine with SQL Server installed on it. If you are using SQL Azure (PaaS) please see the last paragraph.

If you establish a [VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways) between on premises and Azure (Site to Site VPN) or between the client computers and Azure (Point to Site VPN), the client's source IP address will be known and then it would be easy to restrict those in the NSG or firewall.

Anyway, for a user to be able to authenticate to SQL using integrated Windows authentication (contoso\user), the SQL server VM must belong to the Contoso Active Directory domain, or to a domain that Contoso trusts.

So if you join that Azure VM to the Contoso domain, ideally a Contoso's domain controller must be available in Azure. That domain controller can talk with the on premises domain controller through a S2S VPN. Alternatively, you can configure a new domain in Azure and join the SQL server to that new domain, and a trust relationship between this new domain and Contoso - you will need a S2S VPN in this scenario as well.

But even after you have joined the VM to a domain, (remote) users must establish a VPN connection to Azure in order to use Windows authentication (it would not be a good idea to try to use Windows authentication directly in the internet).

You can also evaluate [Azure Active Directory Domain Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-overview), that can help in this scenario, but has other requirements (such as synchronizing users to Azure AD with ADConnect).

You can also evaluate SQL Azure (PaaS), which [supports Azure AD authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication) (but again, you will need to synchronize users with ADConnect).

Comment: Awesome explaination! Thank you. Indeed, my terminology wasn't on par at all; forgive me as this is very new to me. I am infact refering to SQL Azure (PaaS). Currently our active directory has been put into Azure using AADSync. If you could elaborate the differences (if any) between AADSync from ADConnect this answer will be exactly what I need

Comment: DirSync and AADSync are deprecated. You should use ADConnect instead. More info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-hybrid-identity-design-considerations-tools-comparison